# Could not parse the remainder: ' _json' from 'room_name _json'

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-channels, channel

I am trying to learn Django Channels. BUT i am stucked on a problem. Problem is given Below :-

**room.html**

```
<script src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'reconnecting-websocket.js' %}"></script>
<script>
  var roomName = {{ room_name _json }};
  var username = {{ username }};

  var chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
      'ws://' + window.location.host +
      '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');
```

**consumers.py**

```
@login_required
def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name_json': mark_safe(json.dumps(room_name)),
        'username': mark_safe(json.dumps(request.user.username)),
    })
```

**The Problem**

1). When i am trying to open the page in browser, It is showing me `Could not parse the remainder: ' _json' from 'room_name _json'` error.

**Some extra information**

When i notice in IDE , i noticed that , when an error occur in line, then text editor show it like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXbH4.png). It is showing me the red underlines below words.

[image]

I will really appreciate your Help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Btw. I think the browser will tell you on which line the problem occurs, you should provide that, you would notice the typo while typing it into Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `room_name _json` instead of `room_name_json`.

In `var roomName = {{ room_name _json }};`.